# vega editor - the project doesn't start

Tags: reactjs, editor, vega

I ran into a problem. Cloned the project https://github.com/vega/editor

When building, it cannot find files in the public folder.
Can anyone tell me what should be in the files public/spec/vega/index.json and public/spec/vega-lite/index.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub5xf.png)

I tried to paste this format, but it doesn't work

```
    {
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
      "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"a": "A", "b": 28}, {"a": "B", "b": 55}, {"a": "C", "b": 43},
          {"a": "D", "b": 91}, {"a": "E", "b": 81}, {"a": "F", "b": 53},
          {"a": "G", "b": 19}, {"a": "H", "b": 87}, {"a": "I", "b": 52}
       ]
     },
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
       "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
        "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
     }
    }
```